# Trying to use a switch statment to change an image set

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change my image set based on the date, my app works currently and I'm trying to update it so the image set could change weekly depending on what the current date is. But every time that I try and do something, I fail. My current thinking was to use a switch statement to change the variable array content using Unix time as the case.

This is my current code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct User: Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var imageName: String
}

let timeInterval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

var images = ["1", "2", "3", "4"].shuffled()

var images2 = ["160", "161", "162", "163"]

struct ContentView: View {
    
    /// List of users
    @State var users: [User] = [
        User(id: 0, imageName: images[0]),
        User(id: 1, imageName: images[1]),
        User(id: 2, imageName: images[2]),
        User(id: 3, imageName: images[3]),
        User(id: 4, imageName: "back")
    ]
```

This works for the app, but I am a complete beginner to this (and all of this is based on tutorial code) so if there's a better way to do it, or if it's not possible just let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it you want to change, is it the `users` array or one of the image arrays? How would you change it based on date, could you give a simple example?

Comment: It'd be changing the `images` array, to `images2`. The switch statement I had in mind would be something like `switch timeInterval { case 0...1605457614: images = ["1", "2", "3", "4"], default: images = ["160", "161", "162", "163"] }`. But I don't know if this would work, or if where to put this in the code...?

Comment: It looks more like a simple `if/else`, `if timeInterval <= 1605457614 {...`

Comment: I thought that too originally, but from what i read online apparently I was incorrect to use that...

Comment: Either way, I think you need to update your question with a proper example so we can help you. And maybe also explain better exactly what it is you want to do with dates here.